# Infinite Profiles ViewController: Swift Best Practices

Tags: ios, swift, recursion

I building an app with user profiles.  When a user searches for another user or searches their own followers I of course want to display said user profiles.  My question is how should I best set up clicking on user profiles within user profiles while being able to handle the potentially infinite stack of profiles.

Example, user searches for a friends and then looks thru the friends of the friend and then keeps searching and keeps clicking.  I then want the user to be able to back track like in the FB app.

The two options I've thought about are making UIViews within UIViews or more Viewcontrollers.  If anyone has experience with this particular issue or github links to projects that address this issue that'd be amazing thanks!

Also I can post code from my project if anyone would think it'd be helpful but I don't see how it would be at the moment.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, read these links to improve your question: [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) | [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
Some code example will help you get some help.

Answer (score 1):

In general you would just use a regular `UINavigationController` and let the user navigate normally, continually pushing new view controllers onto the stack. You shouldn't really have to worry about performance in the view controllers underneath the top one, unless maybe they are doing something expensive repeatedly (in which case, you would disable those expensive operations in something like `viewDidDisappear:` and re-enable them in `viewDidAppear:`).

The number of view controllers would have to be pretty high for this to cause issues under normal conditions.

Comment: But you have to create each view controller specifically using a navigation controller?

Comment: You create the view controllers normally.You can create them however you want. A navigation controller is just one way to structure a view hierarchy within your app and the one that is commonly used for this sort of paradigm. That is how the FB app and every other app that does something like this works.